# Angular 2 rc.1 testing with ES5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-testing

Using ES5 with Angular 2 RC.1 modules the npm packages provide the `*.umd.js` required to run an Angular 2 app.

```
@angular/core/core.umd.js
@angular/common/common.umd.js
@angular/compiler/compiler.umd.js
@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser.umd.js
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
```

However, there are no `*.umd.js` files for writing Angular 2 tests.

Before the module system, I wrote tests by including `angular2-all-testing.umd.dev.js`. What do I use to write tests now that Angular 2 has split into modules?

Answer (score 1):

The @angular/testing npm module contains testing.umd.js which seems to have most of the test objects needed.  I haven't been able to find MockBackend since moving from beta to rc though.